# Show all posts for people you follow

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 tables, `t_feed` and `t_follow`.

`t_feed` has -

- feedID
- userID
- posts

`t_follow` has -

- followID
- userID
- following

How would I display all the posts for all the users that someone follows?

Comment: Hey @robert! Have you tried somethings out yourself? Where are you having troubles with your SQL statement?

Comment: @robert - I've removed some of the info in your question, because you already (correctly) have placed the php and mysql tags. This is really all we need to know at this stage :) You usually don't have to mention the technology if it's in the tags. FYI

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t_feed.posts FROM t_feed JOIN t_follow ON t_feed.userID = t_follow.following;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="select* from t_follow INNER JOIN t_feed on t_follow.userid=t_feed.userid where userid=".$userid;
```

here $userid is userid of current user. Pass this query to recieve output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a MySQL database for this, you could check out Tizag's tutorial on MySQL Joins: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php:

```
$query = "select feedID, posts from t_follow INNER JOIN t_feed on t_follow.userid = t_feed.userid where userid=".$userid;
```